# Title with English and Greek text

Tags: languages, greek, english

I am having the following code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{refstyle}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields




\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}

 \usepackage{titling}
 \setlength\droptitle{-5cm}
 \renewcommand\maketitlehooka{\raisebox{-0.35\height}
  {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{TUC}}\quad\sffamily \begin{tabular}{l}  {\selectlanguage{english}{TECHNICAL UNIVERSITY OF CRETE}}\\[3ex]{\selectlanguage{english} SCHOOL OF PRODUCTION ENGINEERING AND  MANAGEMENT}\end{tabular}\vskip 24ex}

\renewcommand\maketitlehookb{\vskip 8ex}
\renewcommand\maketitlehookc{\vfill}

\selectlanguage{english}

\title{Vehicle path and traffic flow optimization via automated lane changing on motorways}
\author{Georgantas Antonios}




 \date{Chania 2016}
 \fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

 \begin{document}

 \maketitle

  \newcommand\blankpage{%
   \null
   \thispagestyle{empty}%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \newpage}
    \afterpage{\blankpage}
     \clearpage    


  \chapter*{}
   Η διπλωματική εργασία του Γεωργαντά Αντώνη εγκρίνεται απο την εξεταστική    επιτροπή:


  \clearpage

  \chapter*{Ευχαριστίες}

   \clearpage

   \chapter*{Περιεχόμενα}

     Περίληψη             ....................................................................................... 4

    Κεφάλαιο 1  Εισαγωγή ........................................................................ 6

  \clearpage

   \end{document}
```

I have this code, however I can't get correct transition from greek to english. My main issue is with this part

```
 \selectlanguage{english}

\title{Vehicle path and traffic flow optimization via automated lane changing on motorways}
\author{Georgantas Antonios}
```

It is written in Greek. Can anyone tell me how can this be written in English? Thank you

Comment: Your preamble is strange

Answer (score 2):

```
\selectlanguage{english}
\author{Foo}
\title{Foobar}
```

comes too early  -- at the time of `\maketitle`, the language setting is the default `greek` (since this is the last language specified in the babel settings).

You've to enclose

```
\selectlanguage{english}
\maketitle
\selectlanguage{greek}
```

for example.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{refstyle}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields




\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}

 \usepackage{titling}
 \setlength\droptitle{-5cm}
 \renewcommand\maketitlehooka{\raisebox{-0.35\height}
  {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{TUC}}\quad\sffamily \begin{tabular}{l}  {\selectlanguage{english}{TECHNICAL UNIVERSITY OF CRETE}}\\[3ex]{\selectlanguage{english} SCHOOL OF PRODUCTION ENGINEERING AND  MANAGEMENT}\end{tabular}\vskip 24ex}

\renewcommand\maketitlehookb{\vskip 8ex}
\renewcommand\maketitlehookc{\vfill}


\selectlanguage{english}

\title{Vehicle path and traffic flow optimization via automated lane changing on motorways}
\author{Georgantas Antonios}




 \date{Chania 2016}
 \fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

 \begin{document}
 \selectlanguage{english}
 \maketitle
 \selectlanguage{greek}

 \newcommand\blankpage{%
   \null
   \thispagestyle{empty}%
   \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    \newpage}
    \afterpage{\blankpage}
     \clearpage    


  \chapter*{}
   Η διπλωματική εργασία του Γεωργαντά Αντώνη εγκρίνεται απο την εξεταστική    επιτροπή:


  \clearpage

  \chapter*{Ευχαριστίες}

   \clearpage

   \chapter*{Περιεχόμενα}

     Περίληψη             ....................................................................................... 4

    Κεφάλαιο 1  Εισαγωγή ........................................................................ 6

  \clearpage

   \end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, use

```
 \begin{otherlanguage}{english}
 \maketitle
 \end{otherlanguage}
```

Comment: Great! However, how come the picture isn't shown properly?

Comment: That's the `demo` option for `graphicx ` -- just remove it